# How to specify cell to update in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am writing a script to add a timestamp in another cell whenever a cell within the specified range is updated in Google Sheets. The timestamp should go in column 8 while the editable range in the spreadsheet is from columns 1 through 7. The code I pasted doesn't work because the offset() action will select a cell based on its position relative to the top-left cell in my range - hence, depending on the cell that is updated, the timestamp will go in a different column that its intended column. How do I specify only column 8 to be updated regardless of which cell was edited in my range?

```
function onEdit(e) {
AddTimestampToMetricsList(e) 
}

function AddTimestampToMetricsList(e) {
const rangeModified = e.range

  console.log(rangeModified.getA1Notation())
  console.log(rangeModified.getSheet().getSheetName())
  console.log(rangeModified.getColumn()) 
  console.log(rangeModified.getRow())  

  if(rangeModified.getColumn() > 7) return
  if(rangeModified.getSheet().getSheetName() !== "Metrics List") return
  if(rangeModified.getRow() < 2) return

  rangeModified.offset(0,8).setValue(new Date())

}
```

Comment: Think.  Given that column should always be 8, What would be the offset if the edit was in column 1? What would be the offset if the edit was in column 3? How would you calculate the exact offset from this information?

Answer (score 0):

Fix the column to 8

```
rangeModified.getSheet().getRange(rangeModified.getRow(),8).setValue(new Date())
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Edit columns 1 through 7 and timestamp column 8

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "Enter your sheet name" && e.range,columnStart < 8 && e.range.rowStart > Enter header row && e.value) {
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,8).setValue(new Date())
  }
}
```